# Collect and subtotal duplicate rows in a Variant 2D array

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, vba

I have a dataset in Excel consisting of 20 columns and a varying number of rows, ranging from 20,000 - 50,000.

Each row is a collection of items with one column denoting the quantity of items in the collection and another column denoting the total combined weight of the collection.
Some of these rows are completely identical in all columns, while some are identical in all but quantity and weight.

I want to create a macro that runs through the dataset and "stacks" rows that are duplicate on all other parameters than quantity and weight, and sums these two up.

In other words, a macro that converts this:

```
|Param1|Param2|...|Param18|Quantity|Weight|
| A    | 1    |...| C     | 5      | 12.5 |
| A    | 1    |...| C     | 2      |  5.0 |
| A    | 1    |...| C     | 3      |  7.5 |
| B    | 2    |...| C     | 1      |  2.3 |
| B    | 2    |...| C     | 2      |  4.6 |
```

To this:

```
|Param1|Param2|...|Param18|Quantity|Weight|
| A    | 1    |...| C     | 10     | 25.0 |
| B    | 2    |...| C     | 3      |  6.9 |
```

I know this is possible to do in a simple pivot table, but for a number of reasons this is not viable in this case.

Since I'm dealing with a large dataset, I want to load it all into memory at once rather than reading and writing line by line to speed up performance (as suggested in tip #13 in this great article http://www.databison.com/how-to-speed-up-calculation-and-improve-performance-of-excel-and-vba/). However I'm stuck as to how to make the row operations on the data stored in memory.

So far my code looks like this:

```
Dim r, c, LastRow As Integer
Dim temp_range As Variant

LastRow = Cells(65536, 2).End(xlUp).Row

'Load the data set into memory
temp_range = Sheets("1.1").Range(Sheets("1.1").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("1.1").Cells(LastRow, 20)).Value

'Run through the data set from bottom to top and bulk identical rows together
For r = UBound(temp_range) To LBound(temp_range)
    For i = r - 1 To LBound(temp_range)

        'PSEUDO CODE START HERE
        If row temp_range(r) = row temp_range(i) Then
            temp_range(i,19) = temp_range(r,19) + temp_range(i,19)
            temp_range(i,20) = temp_range(r,19) + temp_range(i,20)
            Delete row temp_range(r)
            Exit For
        End if

        'PSEUDO CODE END HERE

    Next i
Next r
```

I'm stuck at the Pseudo-code section highligted in the code. I simply don't know how to compare the rows, copy quantity and weight from one row to another and then delete the duplicate row in the variant holding the range in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Microsoft Query (SQL) in Excel:**

Such data manipulation operations are ideal for SQL queries. No need of going through the data line by line using VBA:

```
SELECT S1.Param1, S1.Param2, S1.Param18, SUM(S1.Quantity), SUM(S1.Weight) 
FROM [Sheet1$] AS S1 GROUP BY Param1, Param2,Param18
```

**This is guaranteed to run quickly and efficiently via OLE DB**. Whatever VBA code will be much less efficient.

**To refresh the query** at any time simply run the following code from VBA:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.QueryTables(1).Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Where **ws** is the worksheet where you locate the query table.

Either use the **Microsoft Query** from **Data->From other sources->From Microsoft Query** or feel free to use my Add-In: http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-sql-add-in-free/

Comment: I see your point that SQL is more appropriate for such large data set operations, but wouldn't this solution require that I have or set up a SQL server that I can upload the data to, run the SQL query and download it back again to the Excel file?

Comment: Nope. Its an internal native excel feature. No need of installing or configuring anything

Comment: I got this to work and it's a pretty elegant solution! More so than my own below. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Ole DB is much quicker than any VBA you should find. Not to mention less testing and less error prone (less code less errors)

Answer (score 0):

See if you can F8 through this. You will need to go into the VBE's Tools ► References and add *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* for the use of the Scripting.Dictionary object.

```
Sub Stack_Dupes()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, v As Long, k As Long
    Dim vKEYs As Variant, vITMs As Variant, vTMP1 As Variant, vTMP2 As Variant
    Dim sKEY As String, sITM As String
    Dim dITMs As New Scripting.dictionary
    
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .Rows(1).Cells.Copy _
              Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count + 3, 1)
            With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
                vKEYs = .Cells.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 2).Value2
                vITMs = .Cells.Offset(0, .Columns.Count - 2).Resize(.Rows.Count, 2).Value2
                For r = LBound(vKEYs, 1) To UBound(vKEYs, 1)
                    sKEY = Join(Application.Index(vKEYs, r, 0), ChrW(8203))
                    sITM = Join(Application.Index(vITMs, r, 0), ChrW(8203))
                    If dITMs.Exists(sKEY) Then
                        vTMP1 = Split(dITMs.Item(sKEY), ChrW(8203))
                        vTMP2 = Split(sITM, ChrW(8203))
                        vTMP1(0) = CDbl(vTMP1(0)) + CDbl(vTMP2(0))
                        vTMP1(1) = CDbl(vTMP1(1)) + CDbl(vTMP2(1))
                        sITM = Join(vTMP1, ChrW(8203))
                        dITMs.Item(sKEY) = sITM
                    Else
                        dITMs.Add Key:=sKEY, Item:=sITM
                    End If
                Next r
                ReDim vKEYs(1 To (.Columns.Count - 2), 1 To dITMs.Count)
                ReDim vITMs(1 To 2, 1 To dITMs.Count)
                For Each vTMP1 In dITMs.Keys
                    k = k + 1
                    vTMP2 = Split(vTMP1, ChrW(8203))
                    For v = LBound(vTMP2) To UBound(vTMP2)
                        vKEYs(v + 1, k) = vTMP2(v)
                    Next v
                    vTMP2 = Split(dITMs.Item(vTMP1), ChrW(8203))
                    For v = LBound(vTMP2) To UBound(vTMP2)
                        vITMs(v + 1, k) = vTMP2(v)
                    Next v
                Next vTMP1
                .Cells.Offset(.Rows.Count + 3, 0).Resize(UBound(vKEYs, 2), .Columns.Count - 2) = Application.Transpose(vKEYs)
                .Cells.Offset(.Rows.Count + 3, .Columns.Count - 2).Resize(UBound(vITMs, 2), 2) = Application.Transpose(vITMs)
            End With
        End With
    End With
    dITMs.RemoveAll: Set dITMs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Results are written underneath the sample data as follows:

[image: Collate and reorder in Variant Array]

I would be interested in the timed results on larger data sets if you find time to post them back here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated.I have to admit this was a bit too complex for me, mostly due to the fact I haven't used the Scripting.Dictionary object before, so I unfortunately can't deliver the timed results you requested.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article (http://sitestory.dk/excel_vba/arrays-and-ranges.htm, go to middle of the page) on how to delete identical rows that I built some code on. It doesn't solve my original question 100% since it doesn't compare entire rows in the array but rather each column separately in each row, but it turned out to have quite good performance nonetheless.

Here's the code:

```
'I couldn't get the final step of pasting the output array into the new sheet working properly without declaring this option, otherwise the data would be pasted one cell to the right and below where I wanted it.
Option Base 1

Dim r, i, c, LastRow, DeletedRows As Integer
Dim input_array, output_array As Variant
Dim identical As Boolean
Dim s As Worksheet
Dim NewRange As Range

LastRow = Cells(65536, 2).End(xlUp).Row

'Load the data set into memory, consisting of 20 columns of data and a 21th column with no data that is used for marking rows for deletion.
input_array = Sheets("1.1").Range(Sheets("1.1").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("1.1").Cells(LastRow, 21)).Value

DeletedRows = 0

'Run through the data set from bottom to top comparing rows one at a time, copy Quantity and Weight values and mark rows for deletion
For r = UBound(input_array) To 2 Step -1
    For i = r - 1 To 2 Step -1

        'Assume row r and i are identical
        identical = True

        'Run through columns of r and i, flag if non-identical value is found and stop the loop (col 18 is ignored, since this is the "Quantity" column, while col 20 is the "Weight" column)
        For c = 1 To 18
            If input_array(r, c) <> input_array(i, c) And c <> 18 Then
                identical = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c

        ' If no non-identical columns were found, add "Quantity" and "Weight" from row r to row i and mark row r for deletion
        If identical Then
            input_array(i, 18) = input_array(i, 18) + input_array(r, 18)
            input_array(i, 20) = input_array(i, 20) + input_array(r, 20)
            input_array(r, 21) = "_DELETE_"
            DeletedRows = DeletedRows + 1
            Exit For
        End If

    Next i
Next r

' Resize the new array to the size of the old array minus the number of deleted rows
ReDim output_array(UBound(input_array) - DeletedRows, 20)

' Copy rows not marked as deleted from old array to new array
i = 1
For r = 1 To UBound(input_array)
    If input_array(r, 21) <> "_DELETE_" Then
        For c = 1 To 20
            output_array(i, c) = input_array(r, c)
        Next c
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next r

' Create new sheet and 
Set s = Sheets.Add
Set NewRange = s.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(output_array), 20)
NewRange = output_array
```

The macro takes about 30 seconds to reduce 20,000 rows to 3,000 on my computer, which I think is quite good considering the large amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in milliseconds, not seconds. I'm also using arrays and dictionary object. However showing in simpler and more thoughtful implementation. It's faster than using sql against sheet. It can compare any number of columns, just make sure they are included in the KeyIn variable as concatenated string. I also simplify the function by assuming my value to sum is in column 4. You can adjust code for multiple values in other columns. I'm writing from 1 array to another (InAy to OutAy), the dictionary determines if row already existed. The magic happens in the dictionary's Item property. I assign the item property value to the row (r) when a new OutAy row is written. Then when it exists already, I retrieve the row (r) where it was written to OutAy using the item key: d.item(KeyIn) I can then update that value in OutAy(r, 4) with a sum of existing value and new value 'KeyVal'.

This solves the same as sql query aggregate: "Select a, b, c, sum(d) from data group by a, b, c"

Note: add a tools->reference to Microsoft Scripting runtime

```
    sub somesub()
     ...
     data = Range("WhereYourDataIs") 'create data array
     Range("WhereYourDataIs").clear 'assumes you'll output to same location
     data = RemoveDupes(data) 'removedupes and sum values
     Range("A2").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data 'A2 assumes your data headers begin in row 1, column 1
     ...
    End Sub

Function RemoveDupes(InAy As Variant) As Variant
    Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
    ReDim OutAy(1 To UBound(InAy), 1 To 4)
    r = 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(InAy)
        KeyIn = ""
        KeyVal = InAy(i, 4) 'the value field to sum/aggregate if exists
        For c = 1 To 3 'a, b, c metadata to roll up
            KeyIn = KeyIn & InAy(i, c)
        Next c
        If d.Exists(KeyIn) Then
            OutAy(d.item(KeyIn), 4) = OutAy(d.item(KeyIn), 4) + KeyVal 'd.item(KeyIn) is r, set when OutAy row was added. Same as OutAy(r,4)=OutAy(r,4) + KeyVal 
            Else:
            d.Add KeyIn, r 'r is set as the item value referencing the row of the OutAy when it was first added. The reference is used when .Exists is true
            For c = 1 To 4
                OutAy(r, c) = InAy(i, c)
            Next c
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next
    RemoveDupes = OutAy
End Function
```